# What is wrong with this javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first time try javascript 
this image slider is not working and I don't know what is wrong 
this is what I tried to do
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function showDivs (n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
  for (i = 0 ,i < x.length ,i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width:980px;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.left {
  top:50%;
  left: :0;  
}
.right {
  top:50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="mySlides" src= "images/img_fjords.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/img_forest.jpg">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/img_lights.jpg">
  <button class="left" onclick = "plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="right" onclick = "plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your for to

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

instead of:

```
for (i = 0, i < x.length, i++) {
```

(use `;` instead of `,`).

and change `getElementByClassName` to `getElementsByClassName` (notice the s at the end of Elements).

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function showDivs (n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width:980px;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.left {
  top:50%;
  left: :0;  
}
.right {
  top:50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="mySlides" src= "http://placehold.it/500">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/501">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/502">
  <button class="left" onclick = "plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="right" onclick = "plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is Embarrassing
I think I should give up now XD

Comment: @AhmedMoata Everybody starts somewhere! It was also simple typos, I think everyone still makes those mistakes almost daily :)

Comment: Why when I open the page before using the buttons it shows all the images ?

Comment: @AhmedMoata That's your CSS that's doing that, you'll need to edit it to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it.